# Python script for CSV handling

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, concatenation

I'm trying to write a python script whereby the code acts on all CSV files in all subfolders of a particular main folder, where CSVs can have similar names, and the code outputs an edited CSV file for each input CSV. The code is below:

```
import os
import csv
import sys


for root, dirs, files in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
    for filename in files:
        i = 0
        while os.path.exists(str(i)+filename):
            i += 1
        with open(str(i)+filename, "wb") as g:
            symbol = filename.rpartition('_')[-1].rpartition('.')[0] 
            reader = csv.reader(filename)
            writer = csv.writer(g, delimiter='\t', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
            for row in reader:
                row.insert(0, symbol.upper())
                writer.writerow(row)
```

To account for the possibility that I may have similar file names, I'm using an iterative string in the output filename. I also want to add a column into the output CSV such that its content is borrowed from the input filename - this is the purpose of rpartition and the rest of the code. However...my output for one of the CSV inputs looks like:

```
"AA"    "t"
"AA"    "a"
"AA"    "b"
"AA"    "l"
"AA"    "e"
"AA"    "_"
"AA"    "a"
"AA"    "a"
"AA"    "."
"AA"    "c"
"AA"    "s"
"AA"    "v"
```

The "AA" part is correct - its the symbol for that input file. However, I don't know why it proceeds to display the name of the input file (table_aa.csv) in the output, as I want the contents of the input displayed next to the "AA" column.

Could someone please and kindly have a look at the code and let me know?

****************EDIT*****************
Edited the code to:

```
import os
import csv
import sys


for root, dirs, files in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
    for filename in files:
        pathname = os.path.join(root, filename)
        i = 0
        while os.path.exists(str(i)+filename):
            i += 1
        with open(str(i)+filename, "wb") as g:
            symbol = filename.rpartition('_')[-1].rpartition('.')[0]
            reader = csv.reader(pathname)
            writer = csv.writer(g, delimiter='\t', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
            for row in reader:
                row.insert(0, symbol.upper())
                writer.writerow(row)
```

But now the output is:

```
"AA"    "Y"
"AA"    "\"
"AA"    "Y"
"AA"    "2"
"AA"    "\"
"AA"    "t"
"AA"    "a"
"AA"    "b"
"AA"    "l"
"AA"    "e"
"AA"    "_"
"AA"    "a"
"AA"    "a"
"AA"    "."
"AA"    "c"
"AA"    "s"
"AA"    "v"
```

which is again, not the output in the input CSV. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You are not using `root` and `dirs` to create correct path.

```
for filename in [join(root, name)) for name in files)]:
```

you can find more description [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk)

Comment: Sorry, but could you please elaborate a bit more?

Just tried running with the line
     'for filename in files:'
replaced with 
     'for filename in [os.path.join(root, name) for name in files]:'

and it gives me a command promt error.. 'No file or directory exits' (relating to the fact that a number is added in front of the filepath?

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you are passing the input file *name* to `csv.reader`, so that name string is being used as the data source. You need to actually open the input file and pass the file handle to`csv.reader`.

Here's a simplified version of your code that ignores the `os.walk` stuff. It's a good idea to make sure your code processes one file correctly before you get fancy and try to process all files in a directory. Once you have the core process working correctly then you can expand it.

To test this code I created a very simple data file:

#### qdata

```
r0c0,r0c1,r0c2,r0c3
r1c0,r1c1,r1c2,r1c3
r2c0,r2c1,r2c2,r2c3
r3c0,r3c1,r3c2,r3c3
r4c0,r4c1,r4c2,r4c3
```

The code:

#### test.py

```
import csv
import os

filename = 'qdata'
symbol = ['AA']

i = 0
outname = str(i) + filename
while os.path.exists(outname):
    i += 1
    outname = str(i) + filename
print('Saving to name:', outname)    

with open(filename, 'rb') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    with open(outname, "wb") as outfile:
        writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='\t', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        for row in reader:
            row = symbol + row
            writer.writerow(row)
```

The output file:

#### 0qdata

```
"AA"    "r0c0"  "r0c1"  "r0c2"  "r0c3"
"AA"    "r1c0"  "r1c1"  "r1c2"  "r1c3"
"AA"    "r2c0"  "r2c1"  "r2c2"  "r2c3"
"AA"    "r3c0"  "r3c1"  "r3c2"  "r3c3"
"AA"    "r4c0"  "r4c1"  "r4c2"  "r4c3"
```

Note that I used `row = symbol + row` to create a new `row` list. This is more efficient than modifying the list using `.insert` because the `.insert` method has to move all subsequent list items to make room for the inserted item.